# JQuery: Load a View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Ive created a session timeout page, after a session time-outs this page is loaded, once loaded a 1 minute countdown begins which when it hits 0 calls the bellow JQuery.

```
    $(this).on('finish.countdown', function (event) {
         ** Help Needed Here **
    });
```

Inside this method I need to load my Login view located at Home/Login, the controller method looks like this :

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string userName)
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
```

An the question I feel guilty asking... How? ,
I cant seam to find anything about JQuery loading a cshtml view.

Comment: Do you want to load login view to any div or popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do a redirect to that action. Something like this:

```
$(this).on('finish.countdown', function (event) {
    window.location.href = "/Home/Login?userName=" + user;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mikelt21 for helping me and the community, this was what I was looking for:
"window.location.href = "/Home/Login";"